# Calculating percentile on pandas dataframe and assigning binary value to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take a dataframe with one column of imagined 'temperature' data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20070101',periods=3200)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,(3200,1)), columns =list('A'))
df['date'] = dates
df = df[['date','A']]
```

I want to assign all rows with values below the 10th percentile and above the 90th percentile with -1 and 1 respectively (with all else being 0).

Here's a function to try and do that:

```
temp = []
def quantilecalc(x):
    for season in df:
        if season > df.quantile(.9):
            temp.append(1)
        if season < df.quantile(.1):
            temp.append(-1)
        else:
            temp.append(0)
```

When I apply this `quantilecalc(df)` I get the following error:

```
File "C:\\\\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 682, in na_op
raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

I've tried applying it to the specific column of the dataframe `quantilecalc(df['A'])` but this gives the same error. Would really appreciate some expertise...

Comment: Well for starters `for season in df:` iterates over the columns in your df not the rows, also you can use 3 masks to set all the rows that meet the criteria instead of looping

Comment: Apologies, my python skills aren't great. I don't know about masks, are you saying I can change this to iterate over rows and it will work? If so - how do I go about doing this?

Comment: basically you can do something like `df.loc[df['A'] > df['A'].quanteil(0.9), 'A'] = 1` and so on

Comment: Thanks, I created a new column `df['temp'] = ""` and applied this `df.loc[df['A'] > df['A'].quantile(0.9), 'temp'] = 1` which worked

Comment: So now you can do the same for the other 2 conditions and this will be faster than looping

Comment: Done - thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@EdChum provided this answer:

create a new column `df['temp'] = ""` and applied this:

```
df.loc[df['A'] > df['A'].quantile(0.9), 'temp'] = 1
df.loc[df['A'] < df['A'].quantile(0.1), 'temp'] = -1
```

Thanks!